# Slow single connection internetspeed

Tags: networking

So my problem is that my downloads only seem to use all available download speed if they are multi connected to the file server,
if i download a file with a single connection i only get a very low download rate, doesn't matter which server.

Multi connection speed test:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o3Ue.png,
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/wec7K.png

Single connection speed test:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV9V3.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK9ec.png

You can see that i get like 10 times the speed if i try to download the Nvida driver with more then one connection via jdownloader.

A technician was already here but he was not competently and never heard of single and multi connection so he could not find any error and said that's a problem of my PC.
I tried different Browsers and resetting my network settings

I am using Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller and i had no such problem with my former internet provider.

If you have any suggestions i would be very thankful.

**Edit :** I tried to download the Nvida Drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 and now i having normal speed like 400 Mbits or higher. So the problem is somehow Windows related.

**Edit2 :** I am using Windows 10 updated to the latest version

**Edit 3:** I fixed it myself i somehow had **"autotuninglevel=disable"** 
I changed it to **"autotuninglevel=normal"** with **"netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal**" and now everything is normal again.

Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Can you please define technically what you are trying to do?  I have not heard of this either. I use a single connection on only one NIC (if both wired and wireless exist) and I get excellent speed.

Comment: Try a different operating system, e.g. Live Linux system (boot from DVD or USB-stick) like Knoppix or the Ubuntu installer DVD and compare the results.

Comment: @John i just want to download a file via the browser with fullspeed withoute using a tool like jdownloader to make multiple connections ... it should download with fullspeed

Comment: On a good system, one network connection will do it just fine - full speed.

Comment: @Robert i tried it with Ubuntu 18.04 got no problems with it

Comment: @John yeah that should be the normal case but i think i somehow fucked up my windows or so but i dont know how....

Comment: Why do you always talk of "Windows" instead of exactly naming the version? When posting on Stackexchange please always include such important details! May be your Windows is just too old to have a good network configuration. Older Windows versions were not prepared for high-speed connections.

Comment: @Robert its Windows 10 updated to the latest version sry for forgetting it, i thought that would be the normal case so i did not mention it

Comment: In this case, I suggest doing a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link. Try first with Keep Everything

Comment: @Franz I'm glad you were able to figure it out. Please post your solution as a real Answer post to your Question post, and then click the check mark outline next to your Answer post to mark it as the officially accepted Answer, so this post is marked as resolved. SU encourages answering one's own questions in this way in this situation.